# Looping Sheets and Refreshing Queries

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with this, and not sure how to go forward.
I have a workbook which has 4 "Display" sheets.
These have data and charts, and are to be shown on a large screen with stats and figures.

The data is database linked queries, which need to refresh throughout the day.
The worksheets need to continuously loop around throughout the day.

My code below is the entire code as I thought it would be easier to see the whole picture.

If I step through AutoLoad, it works exactly as I want. It refreshes the query, then loads the worksheet for 5 seconds (as input in J2).

If I execute the code, it loads the first worksheet ("Daily Dispatch Figures"), but the chart appears completely black.
After 5 seconds, the 2nd worksheet loads ("Sales & GP Today"), but again the chart is completely black.

After this, it never shows anything else on screen. It permanently stays stuck on the "Sales & GP Today" worksheet.

If I hit ESC, the code exits, and the worksheet at the point in the loop I broke on is shown, so the code is running in the background.

I have previously tried setting the queries to auto refresh every 1 minute and not even touching the refresh in VBA, but this appears to be ignored whilst any "looping" code is running, and only refresh once I stop the code, so whilst the looping worked (using exactly the same methodology as below), the data wasn't updating.

This is Excel 2013.

```
Sub Refresh()
RefreshQueries
MsgBox "Queries Refreshed"

End Sub



Sub RefreshQueries()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim DispatchTarget As String
Dim RepTargets As String
Dim DispatchesSql As String
Dim SalesGPSql As String
Dim RepvTargetSql As String
Dim x As Long
Dim Y As Integer

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblMonthlyTargets")

For x = 2 To tbl.ListRows.Count + 1
    If x = tbl.ListRows.Count + 1 Then
    RepTargets = RepTargets & "('" & tbl.Range(x, 1).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 2).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 3) & "') "
    Else
    RepTargets = RepTargets & "('" & tbl.Range(x, 1).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 2).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 3) & "'), "
    End If
Next x


Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblDespTarget")
 DispatchTarget = tbl.Range(2, 1).Value

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblMonthlyTargets")
MonthTarget = tbl.Range(Month(Date) + 1, 2).Value



' Sets Dispatches Summary Sql
DispatchesSql = _
"Select sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) as TotalValue, " & _
DispatchTarget & " as 'Target', " & _
"case WHEN " & DispatchTarget & " -sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) > 0  " & _
"THEN " & DispatchTarget & " -sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) " & _
"Else 0.00 End as 'Remainder' " & _
"from delivery_header " & _
"join delivery_line_item on delivery_line_item.dli_dh_id = delivery_header.dh_id " & _
"join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_id = delivery_line_item.dli_oli_id " & _
"where  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,delivery_header.dh_datetime),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) "



' Sets Sales GP SQL
SalesGPSql = _
"Select sum(order_header_total.oht_net) as 'TotalNet', " & _
"sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) as 'TotalGP' " & _
"from order_header " & _
"join order_header_total on order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
"where order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
"and dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,order_header.oh_datetime),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) "



' Sets Rep v Target SQL

RepvTargetSql = _
"With SalesPeople as (select X.Person, X.Month, X.Target From (Values    " & _
RepTargets & _
") as X (Person, Month, Target))   " & _
"SELECT user_detail.ud_username,  " & _
"isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) AS 'Net Total ',  " & _
"CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END AS 'Target',  " & _
"CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END) - isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) < = 0  " & _
"THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END) - isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) END AS 'Remaining' "
RepvTargetSql = RepvTargetSql & _
"FROM user_detail " & _
"LEFT JOIN ( " & _
    "SELECT user_detail.ud_id, sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) AS Net " & _
    "FROM order_header " & _
    "JOIN order_header_total ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN order_header_detail ON order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN user_detail ON user_detail.ud_id = order_header_detail.ohd_sales_rep " & _
    "WHERE dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, order_header.oh_datetime), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) AND order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
    "GROUP BY user_detail.ud_id ) AS TodaysTotal ON TodaysTotal.ud_id = user_detail.ud_id " & _
"LEFT JOIN ( " & _
    "SELECT user_detail.ud_id, sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) AS Net " & _
    "FROM order_header " & _
    "JOIN order_header_total ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN order_header_detail ON order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN user_detail ON user_detail.ud_id = order_header_detail.ohd_sales_rep " & _
    "WHERE dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, order_header.oh_datetime), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) AND order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
    "GROUP BY user_detail.ud_id " & _
    ") AS MonthTotals ON MonthTotals.ud_id = user_detail.ud_id " & _
"JOIN (SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) + 1) - (DATEDIFF(wk, getdate(), dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) * 2) -  " & _
    "(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DaysLeft " & _
    ") AS WorkingDaysLeft ON 1 = 1 " & _
"JOIN SalesPeople on SalesPeople.Person = ud_username and SalesPeople.Month = datename(month,getdate()) " & _
"WHERE user_detail.ud_active = 1 " & _
"ORDER BY user_detail.ud_username "

' Debug.Print DispatchesSql

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespatches").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = DispatchesSql
    .Refresh
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qrySalesGPToday").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = SalesGPSql
    .Refresh
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryRepDaily").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = RepvTargetSql
    .Refresh
End With


With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespPicksOpenOrders").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With


End Sub






Sub AutoLoad()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim LoopTime As String

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblTime")
 LoopTime = tbl.Range(2, 1).Value

LoopTime = Sheets("Targets").Range("J2").Value

Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo err_handler
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'sets Sql statements for today in queries
RefreshQueries

'Refresh Despatch ready for screen showing
RefreshDespatch

Do Until 1 = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Loads up Daily Dispatch Figures worksheet
Sheets("Daily Dispatch Figures").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:C36").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("DailyDespatchChart").Activate


'Refreshes Sales ready for next screen
RefreshSales

newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)


Application.Wait Waittime


'Loads up "Sales & GP Today" worksheet

Sheets("Sales & GP Today").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B35").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SalesGPTodayChart").Activate

'Refresh Daily ready for next screen
RefreshDaily


newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime



'Loads up Rep Daily Targets worksheet

Sheets("Rep Daily Targets").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B36").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("RepDailyChart").Activate

'Refreshes Live ready for next screen
RefreshLive


newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime


'Loads up Live Summary worksheet

Sheets("Live Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B4").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select

'Refreshes Despatch ready for next screen
RefreshDespatch


newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime



Loop


err_handler:
    If Err.Number = 18 Then
        EndReport
        MsgBox "Report Cancelled"
    End If

End Sub

Sub RefreshDespatch()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespatches").ODBCConnection
  .BackgroundQuery = False
  .Refresh
End With

End Sub

Sub RefreshSales()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qrySalesGPToday").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub

Sub RefreshDaily()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryRepDaily").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub

Sub RefreshLive()

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespPicksOpenOrders").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub


Sub EndReport()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this, by forcing a Do While to delay the code execution for 1 second.
I think 2013 is executing the code so fast, that it's trying to execute the next line before it's completed what it was doing on screen.

```
Sub Refresh()
RefreshQueries
MsgBox "Queries Refreshed"


End Sub



Sub RefreshQueries()




Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim DispatchTarget As String
Dim RepTargets As String
Dim DispatchesSql As String
Dim SalesGPSql As String
Dim RepvTargetSql As String
Dim x As Long
Dim Y As Integer

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblMonthlyTargets")

For x = 2 To tbl.ListRows.Count + 1
    If x = tbl.ListRows.Count + 1 Then
    RepTargets = RepTargets & "('" & tbl.Range(x, 1).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 2).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 3) & "') "
    Else
    RepTargets = RepTargets & "('" & tbl.Range(x, 1).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 2).Value & "', '" & tbl.Range(x, 3) & "'), "
    End If
Next x


Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblDespTarget")
 DispatchTarget = tbl.Range(2, 1).Value

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblMonthlyTargets")
MonthTarget = tbl.Range(Month(Date) + 1, 2).Value



' Sets Dispatches Summary Sql
DispatchesSql = _
"Select sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) as TotalValue, " & _
DispatchTarget & " as 'Target', " & _
"case WHEN " & DispatchTarget & " -sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) > 0  " & _
"THEN " & DispatchTarget & " -sum(isnull(((delivery_line_item.dli_qty*(order_line_item.oli_total_margin/order_line_item.oli_qty_required))/order_line_item.oli_price_per),0)) " & _
"Else 0.00 End as 'Remainder' " & _
"from delivery_header " & _
"join delivery_line_item on delivery_line_item.dli_dh_id = delivery_header.dh_id " & _
"join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_id = delivery_line_item.dli_oli_id " & _
"where  dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,delivery_header.dh_datetime),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) "



' Sets Sales GP SQL
SalesGPSql = _
"Select sum(order_header_total.oht_net) as 'TotalNet', " & _
"sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) as 'TotalGP' " & _
"from order_header " & _
"join order_header_total on order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
"where order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
"and dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,order_header.oh_datetime),0) = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) "



' Sets Rep v Target SQL

RepvTargetSql = _
"With SalesPeople as (select X.Person, X.Month, X.Target From (Values    " & _
RepTargets & _
") as X (Person, Month, Target))   " & _
"SELECT user_detail.ud_username,  " & _
"isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) AS 'Net Total ',  " & _
"CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END AS 'Target',  " & _
"CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END) - isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) < = 0  " & _
"THEN 0 ELSE (CASE WHEN WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft = 0 THEN SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0) ELSE (SalesPeople.Target - isnull(MonthTotals.Net, 0)) / WorkingDaysLeft.DaysLeft END) - isnull(TodaysTotal.Net, 0) END AS 'Remaining' "
RepvTargetSql = RepvTargetSql & _
"FROM user_detail " & _
"LEFT JOIN ( " & _
    "SELECT user_detail.ud_id, sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) AS Net " & _
    "FROM order_header " & _
    "JOIN order_header_total ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN order_header_detail ON order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN user_detail ON user_detail.ud_id = order_header_detail.ohd_sales_rep " & _
    "WHERE dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, order_header.oh_datetime), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) AND order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
    "GROUP BY user_detail.ud_id ) AS TodaysTotal ON TodaysTotal.ud_id = user_detail.ud_id " & _
"LEFT JOIN ( " & _
    "SELECT user_detail.ud_id, sum(order_header_total.oht_total_margin) AS Net " & _
    "FROM order_header " & _
    "JOIN order_header_total ON order_header_total.oht_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN order_header_detail ON order_header_detail.ohd_oh_id = order_header.oh_id " & _
    "JOIN user_detail ON user_detail.ud_id = order_header_detail.ohd_sales_rep " & _
    "WHERE dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, order_header.oh_datetime), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) AND order_header.oh_sot_id = 1 " & _
    "GROUP BY user_detail.ud_id " & _
    ") AS MonthTotals ON MonthTotals.ud_id = user_detail.ud_id " & _
"JOIN (SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) + 1) - (DATEDIFF(wk, getdate(), dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) * 2) -  " & _
    "(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, getdate()) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DaysLeft " & _
    ") AS WorkingDaysLeft ON 1 = 1 " & _
"JOIN SalesPeople on SalesPeople.Person = ud_username and SalesPeople.Month = datename(month,getdate()) " & _
"WHERE user_detail.ud_active = 1 " & _
"ORDER BY user_detail.ud_username "

' Debug.Print DispatchesSql

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespatches").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = DispatchesSql
    .Refresh
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qrySalesGPToday").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = SalesGPSql
    .Refresh
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryRepDaily").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandText = RepvTargetSql
    .Refresh
End With


With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespPicksOpenOrders").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With


End Sub






Sub AutoLoad()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim LoopTime As String
Dim Start As Single

Set tbl = Sheets("Targets").ListObjects("tblTime")
 LoopTime = tbl.Range(2, 1).Value

LoopTime = Sheets("Targets").Range("J2").Value

Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo err_handler
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'sets Sql statements for today in queries
RefreshQueries

'Refresh Despatch ready for screen showing
Start = Timer
'wait 1 sec...
Do While Start + 1 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
RefreshDespatch


Do Until 1 = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Loads up Daily Dispatch Figures worksheet
Sheets("Daily Dispatch Figures").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:C36").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("DailyDespatchChart").Activate


'Refreshes Sales ready for next screen
Start = Timer
'wait 1 sec...
Do While Start + 1 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
RefreshSales




newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)


Application.Wait Waittime


'Loads up "Sales & GP Today" worksheet

Sheets("Sales & GP Today").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B35").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SalesGPTodayChart").Activate

'Refresh Daily ready for next screen
Start = Timer
'wait 1 sec...
Do While Start + 1 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
RefreshDaily


newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime



'Loads up Rep Daily Targets worksheet

Sheets("Rep Daily Targets").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B36").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("RepDailyChart").Activate

'Refreshes Live ready for next screen
Start = Timer
'wait 1 sec...
Do While Start + 1 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
RefreshLive




newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime


'Loads up Live Summary worksheet

Sheets("Live Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Range("A1:B4").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Range("A1").Select

'Refreshes Despatch ready for next screen
Start = Timer
'wait 1 sec...
Do While Start + 1 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
RefreshDespatch


newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + LoopTime
Waittime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)

Application.Wait Waittime



Loop


err_handler:
    If Err.Number = 18 Then
        EndReport
        MsgBox "Report Cancelled"
    End If


End Sub

Sub RefreshDespatch()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespatches").ODBCConnection
  .BackgroundQuery = False
  .Refresh
End With

End Sub

Sub RefreshSales()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qrySalesGPToday").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub

Sub RefreshDaily()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryRepDaily").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub

Sub RefreshLive()

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("qryDespPicksOpenOrders").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub


Sub EndReport()

Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

End Sub
```